# Why is my car making a knocking noise?

Tags: oil, chrysler, old-cars, knock, sebring

2001 Chrysler Sebring lxi 4 door. 2.7 liter 24 valve[image]Why is my car making a knocking noise? It will start it, drive yet when i press the gas it makes a knocking sound and takes off very slow

Comment: It didnt have oil in it when i checked. Put 4 quarts of oil it started then cut off. Got running this morning and drive it home.

Comment: It was running while 4 quarts low on oil? Was the knock before or after you added the oil?

Answer (score 2):

The 2001 Sebring with the 2.7 engine holds 5 quarts of oil.

Sounds like you ran it out of oil. That would make the engine knock and do all kinds of bad things to the internal engine parts.

If you added oil and it won't run correctly now, you probably have major engine damage. This means you will have to have the engine inspected and repaired/replaced.

Costly lesson about checking oil levels on a regular basis. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Kinda sounds like you lost the lower end of the engine.  How much oil does the engine hold? If it holds 4qts and you had to add 4qts. It was most likely ran with out oil and took out the lower end(crankshaft main bearings and piston connecting rod  bearings.) With the information you given that would be my guess. But you should take it to a shop if this is beyond your mechanical  skills.

Comment: pistons are the things that go up and down really fast? There like cars horse power? ?

Comment: Something like that.  But you most likely have bad bearings now since you ran with no oil. The bearings are on the crankshaft.